# Warning: include_once(../settings/settings.php): failed to open stream - but the path is actually right?

Tags: php, path, include-path

```
Warning: include_once(../settings/settings.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Project/classes/user.class.php on line 2

Warning: include_once(): Failed opening '../settings/settings.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.1/lib/php') in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Snapshot/classes/user.class.php on line 2
```

But the file location is actually right? It even gives me auto path fill suggestions (visual code plugin) to that path!

Why does this happen is this something to do with the / or the second warning line?

So I'm trying to include the **settings.php** file from inside the **User.class.php** file with the following code.

```
include_once("../settings/settings.php");
```

../ -> goes back into the root folder

settings/ -> enters settings folder

settings.php -> should locate the needed .php file

[image]

[image]

Comment: If index.php is doing the including of a file and that's including another file and so on its relative from index.php not the file that's including. Try: `include_once("./settings/settings.php");`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace

```
include_once("../settings/settings.php");
```

with

```
include_once(__DIR__ . "/../settings/settings.php");
```

`__DIR__` will resolve in the absolute path of the file where this constant is used. You can navigate your folders from that.

Comment: Thanks that worked, is there no other way around it?

Comment: If you want use relative path, you need to set the `include_path` with something that you expect. `set_include_path('/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Project/');` at the top of your entrypoint, then try  with `include_once "settings/settings.php"`. I would advise to not do that. Relative url aren't predictable.

Answer (score 1):

Use an absolute path to the file. You can use **$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']** or create a const variable **BASEPATH** that you can easily set root directory value to.

```
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/settings/settings.php");
```

**OR**

```
define('BASEPATH', "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs");
include_once(BASEPATH."/settings/settings.php");
```

Comment: Warning: include_once(/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/settings/settings.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Snapshot/classes/User.class.php on line 2



Warning: include_once(): Failed opening '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/settings/settings.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.1/lib/php') in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Snapshot/classes/User.class.php on line 2

Comment: I tried your edit and that still gave the same error I used @Federkun his post and that worked, thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where you call your class. Better yet is to use configuration file to fulfil the require/include path like every PHP framework does.